# How do I install a .vimball Plugin?

Tags: plugin-system, vimball

I was given a plugin for Vim.
It came in something called a `.vimball`.

- What am I meant to do with this exactly?
- Where do I put it?
- Do I need to be root to install it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply open the vimball file in Vim and then execute `:source %`.

It will move the files to their appropriate folders in your `~/.vim` directory.

You don't need to be root as it just copies files to your `~/.vim` directory. You can delete it after you have sourced the vimball file

Comment: See also :help vimball for additional vimball-related commands (in vim 7 and up I think).

Answer (score 8):

#### `:UseVimball path` instead of `:so [name].vba` for vim8-packages/dein/vim-plug/minpac

If you use vim8 pack paths or a plugin manager which supports local plugins (e.g. [dein](https://github.com/Shougo/dein.vim) or [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug)), you might want to install a [*vimball*](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_vimball.txt.html#vimball) (`.vba[.gz]`) into a specific directory and not merge it with your `~/.vim` directory.

#### Example: Installation of [*Vis* (Visual Block Cmds)](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#VIS) by Charles Campbell (DrChip)

**vim8 pack path/minpac**

If you use the [package](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#packages) feature of vim8 or [minpac](https://github.com/k-takata/minpac), `~/.vim/pack/manual/start/vis` would be a sensible location. The installation steps would be

```
$ vim http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vbafiles/vis.vba.gz
:UseVimball ~/.vim/pack/manual/start/vis
```

If you use [dein](https://github.com/Shougo/dein.vim) or [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug), you would install the vimball not in a pack path but one of your choice and would add this plugin with a plugin manager specific line to your `$MYVIMRC`:

**dein**

```
$ vim http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vbafiles/vis.vba.gz
:UseVimball ~/.vim/dein-manual/vis
```

```
dein#add('~/.vim/dein-manual/vis')
```

**vim-plug**

```
$ vim http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vbafiles/vis.vba.gz
:UseVimball ~/.vim/plugged-manual/vis
```

```
Plug '~/.vim/plugged-manual/vis'
```

#### Installing new version of a default plugin

However, note that default plugins (e.g. *netrw*) are sourced before plugins installed into a vim 8 `packpath`. The source order is:

1. `$HOME/.vim/plugin`
2. `$VIM/plugin`
3. `$VIMRUNTIME/plugin`
4. `$HOME/.vim/pack/*/start/*/plugin`

This means installing a newer *netrw* version into a `packpath` is not as straightforward as one would think. See for details [Vim 8 packages, how do I overwrite a default package?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11604/vim-8-packages-how-do-i-overwrite-a-default-package).

Comment: Note, `:UseVimball` needs that path to exist (e.g. `mkdir -p ~/.vim/pack/manual/start/vis`) as the vimball code doesn't understand the vim8 package feature and doesn't expect missing parent directories. Worse, the failure is silent.