# Vim 8 packages, how do I overwrite a default package?

Tags: packages

I have installed [Dr. Chip's `netrw`](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#NETRW%20) from his homepage, since it is newer and more often updated than the files that are part of the main Vim distribution.

Before Vim 8 I always sued the Vimball install method, by opening the `.vba` and running `:source %`.  But, now that Vim 8 added the packages mechanism I decided to use that.  I have my packages under:

```
~/.vim/pack/packages/start/
~/.vim/pack/packages/opt/
```

So to install NETRW as a package I did:

```
cd ~/.vim/pack/packages/start/
wget  http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vbafiles/netrw.vba.gz
mkdir netrw.vim
gunzip netrw.vba.gz
vim netrw.vba
:UseVimball ~/.vim/pack/packages/start/netrw.vim
```

And it installed correctly.  But now when I edit a file and use a `netrw` command, say, `:Lexplore` I'm not sure which `netrw` is being used.  If I do:

```
vim foo
:scriptnames
  1: /etc/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/archlinux.vim
  3: ~/.vim/vimrc
  (...)
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 24: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
 25: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 26: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 27: ~/.vim/pack/packages/start/csv.vim/plugin/csv.vim
 28: ~/.vim/pack/packages/start/csv.vim/ftdetect/csv.vim
 29: ~/.vim/pack/packages/start/netrw.vim/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 30: /usr/share/vim/vim80/scripts.vim
```

So the distribution `netrw` runs first (20) and then runs the installed one (29).  If I add `packloadall` to my `vimrc` the situation changes:

```
  1: /etc/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/archlinux.vim
  3: ~/.vim/vimrc
  4: ~/.vim/pack/packages/start/csv.vim/plugin/csv.vim
  5: ~/.vim/pack/packages/start/netrw.vim/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
  (...)
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
```

And the installed `netrw` in my directory runs first (5).  Yet, the Vim distribution `netrw` still runs (23)!

- Which `netrw` will Vim use when I do, say, `:Lexplore`?  It appears to use the new (Vimball installed one) for `:Lexplore` but I'm not sure since `:h pi_netrw` gives me the new document, but `:h netrw` gives me the old documentation (the one that comes with Vim).
- Running `:helptags ~/.vim/pack/packages/start/netrw.vim/doc` does not help with the documentation problem above (i.e. I get sometimes the new one and sometimes the old one).  Is there something I'm doing wrong with this?
- Does Vim *always* give preference to plugins/scripts/autoload commands that are in `$VIM` (default `~/.vim`) above the ones in `$VIMRUNTIME`?

Comment: If you want to be sure that you have only one version of netrw installed, you can use the [NetrwClean](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#NETRWCLEAN) plugin to remove all versions of netrw (the one in your user directory `~/.vim` and the one in the system directory `/usr/share/vim`). Then you can reinstall the newest version of netrw from Dr. Chip's website, and you are sure that only this version will be running now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `netrwPlugin.vim` you'll find:

```
if &cp || exists("g:loaded_netrwPlugin")
 finish
endif
```

So just set this in your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:loaded_netrwPlugin = 1
```

---

If they both use the same variable (`g:loaded_netrwPlugin`) then they only one can be loaded and it is sufficient to either use `packloadall` or source `~/.vim/pack/packages/start/netrw.vim/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim` at the end of your `.vimrc`.

Comment: But then it also won't load the netrw from `~/.vim/pack/../netrw`?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker right, updated

Comment: You're right, both use the same variable.  And even more, they set the variable to the version of the plugin being loaded, which allows to test which file is in operation.  I still wonder how I fix the documentation tags but that should be another question.  Many thanks!